# Scala - control structure

Tags: scala

I am entirely new to `Scala` world and trying to understand few `Scala` concepts. From [here](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/wikla/OTS/Sisalto/examples/html/ch09.html) I got below piece of `Scala Code`.

```
def twice(op: Double => Double, x: Double) = op(op(x))
```

and by calling `twice(_ + 1, 5)` returning the result `Double = 7.0`. But I couldn't able to understand what `_ + 1` and `op: Double => Double` really means. Can someone able to explain me the above piece of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
op: Double => Double
```

`op` is a function that takes a value of type `Double` and returns a new value of type `Double`.

```
_ + 1
```

`_` is the placeholder for an argument to this anonymous function (i.e. this function is described but has no name. Once it is received in the `twice` method it has the name `op`.)  So this function takes an argument, adds 1 to it, and returns the new value.

If you call `twice(_ + 1, 5)` you can think about it like this: `op(op(x))` --> `op(op(5))` --> `op(5 + 1)` --> `op(6)` --> `6 + 1` --> `7` (or `7.0` because it is of type `Double`)

Comment: How comes `op(5+1)`, as far my understanding, it should be `op(_ + 1)` right?

Comment: `op` is `_ + 1` so `op(x)` becomes `x + 1`.  Likewise `op(5)` becomes `5 + 1`.